# Language system design

Tags: codeigniter, system

I am about to implement a language system into my codeigniter project. (following this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-language-support-in-codeigniter/), but I am a bit stuck with the thinking process.

The website will contain alot of text so there would have to be alot of indivudual language files like error_english.php, user_english.php etc...

But I'm wondering, is that the right way to go? Like for example what if I have a page with different language files loaded in it because it has alot of text and I have to load 1 word, something like Firsname or something.

That would mean I'd have to load user_english.php while that will contain for example more than 100's rows of texts. Wouldn't there be alot of loading because of this, just for 1 word? There would be so many unneeded arrays.

Does anyone know a good design/routing pattern to be able to keep the server loadtime/performance as it's best?

Comment: Can you simplify your question. Its unclear

Comment: What I am wondering is, what would be the best way of creating a multiple language based website with the texts defined in array's. If I have a .php script full with the array's for all of the errors, and I have to load it in on a page for just using 1 of the errors, it would load alot of unneeded arrays. What is the best design pattern to have the best optimalized language system?

Comment: you can call it by using id. So you get output with only one

Answer (score 0):

language packs are simply key-value pairs. yes, you load thousands of lines if need be and it works fine.  One way to mitigate that line count somewhat is to have different language pack files for different sections of site.
so you could have an error file and do:

```
$this->load->language('errors');
```

But really it doesn't make a practical difference for speed - it is an organisational thing.

I have extended mine to use field substitution.  Language packs also provide a way to separate code from presentation - i always use them in models even if I am only writing in english because it forms a separation between code logic and outputs that makes the code easier to read.

so if you put this in your helpers:

```
function lang_sub( $str, $params = '')
{
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $return_string =  $str;
    if (array_key_exists($str, $CI->lang->language))
    {
        // the str is a key. so it only is a one line substitution.
        $return_string = $CI->lang->line($str);
        if (is_array($params))// if a parameter array is sent, substitute the strings %s in order.
        {
            $return_string = vsprintf($r, $params);
        }
    }
    return $return_string;
}
```

you can do something like this in your language entry:

```
$lang['login_message'] = "Welcome %s good to see you again! we as last saw your on %s.";
```

and in your model can do something like:

```
$welcome_message = lang_sub('login_message',array($username,$last_seen));
```

note that it is a good idea to consider naming and collisions of your entries before you start.

good luck!